# recommended way to handle this case in .NET for web application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, web-services

I am relatively new to web development and am trying to figure out what would be the recommended way to deal with my current situation.

All of this needs to be in the .NET framework.This is a very simple use case, but I am required to deal with a bigger problem here.

Here is the flow of things:

- Client clicks a button on a page: "Calculate Sum"
- This invokes a call to the webservice which calculates the sum and returns some extra info on how to render it on the html page
- The client receives this info from the webservice and populates one of the variables in the javascript that is used in the resulting page and the extra info is used to render the html page
- The resulting page would have a button; when clicked would redirect to a third party application. It would then process this request and send a POST back to one the URLs I have specified. I am then required to consume the info (string) that they would send back.

Let me know if I am not clear in any of this and if you want me to specify more info. This is more about learning on the job and so I am trying to find out the best way to solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking for confirmation that your flow is correct or for specific code examples of the steps within the process?  Or something else?

Comment: I am sure about the steps, but I am not sure how to go about setting up the architecture for all of this. Do I need to use ASP.NET or something else or what ?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like, if as you say everything must be in .NET framework, then you can use Visual Studios to develop this project in VB or C#. Essentially, the page that initially sends the request to the web service would be built as a .aspx webpage. Then you can build a web service in C# or VB .asmx which handles the calculation, returns a result that is parsed by javascript on another asp.net web page and produces a button to send the gathered data as a POST to another URL.

Comment: I have some gaps in my knowledge. I know how to create the webservice. What I'd like to understand is, how can the page make a request to that webservice ? Do I need to use some framework (.Net MVC) or what ?

Comment: Also, how will it be able to handle the response from the webservice ?

Comment: If you'd like you can use a basic HTML form to send a post request to the web service. Check out the "Test" pages for the functions in your web service and view their source code to see what a sample HTML form could look like for your web service. As far as handling a response, you could javascript to parse the response on the page or use ASP.Net functions to parse the response. The response will come back as XML and there are some very nice built in libraries in .NET for handling these.

Comment: @brainydexter You could also use some Ajax and updatepanels to do the postback (which means the whole page doesn't refresh) and do the server side processing without the user even knowing.